# Crawling deep file paths - long URL - Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, error, crawling

**SharePoint 2010 search crawl error:**

*The SharePoint item being crawled returned an error when requesting data from the web service.( Error from SharePoint site: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.)*

If I 'open item in a new window', 'The webpage cannot be found' pageerror shows up, but I'm able to navigate deep into the list folder hierarchy and open it.

My thought is that **doc path is to long** (what's unbelievable in a ECM) and is preventing the file index.

The document(s) and folder(s) were created/uploaded via WebDav.

Iideas?

Comment: and what is the doc path ?

Comment: Do you see similar errors in your ULS Log?  I don't always go by the Search Log, it tends to be incomplete.

Comment: Steve B, doc path is the file url that shows up in the crawl log as an error and with the message above.

Comment: MichaelF, the error in the ULSLog looks like this,
CSTS3Accessor::Init fails, Url [ITEMFULLURL], hr=80042616  [sts3handler.cxx:312]  d:\office\source\search\native\gather\protocols\sts3\sts3handler.cxx

Comment: after a deeper look, I've realized that the item is successful indexed but the same item triggers 2 Crawl Log errors: the above mentioned and [listfullUrl]/forms/dispform?id=[itemId] with the same message of the first one.
The issue it could be caused by some kind of metadata, cause I easily created more files at the same level or below it.

Comment: Strangely we are now seeing errors like this in our Crawl log.  Not sure if its the cause, but this looks like a solution to me: http://serverfault.com/questions/122543/error-in-the-site-data-web-service-when-performing-crawl

Comment: for deeper paths , long path tool software will be very helpful